# WiFi is not working in Loki 0.4.1 (HP Pavilion)

Tags: release-loki, wifi, ethernet

I am a total newbie here, and cant figure out how to get the Wifi to work on my laptop **(HP Pavilion AB Series)**.

Steps I did take:

1. Reinstalled Elementary with Ethernet connected and checking on two options "Install Updates" & "Download 3rd Party Software". I also ticked the Secure Boot Option, and inserted a password there.
2. Ran the following code through the terminal:

   > sudo apt-get update && sudo apt-get upgrade

After which I promptly restarted my laptop to see whether it was fixed.

--

Questions:

1. After I reinstalled it, the Status bar options, does show Ethernet but doesnt show my Wifi which is called "Siddhant"
2. Is the problem with my secure boot?

Please do tell if you need me to run some other codes to provide a better look at what is the supposed problem.

---

EDIT: I SOLVED THIS BY SIMPLY GOING INTO THE BIOS AND DISABLING **SECURE BOOT**. Took me a week to find this out, but I hope this helps out anyone with similar issues.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I SOLVED THIS BY SIMPLY GOING INTO THE BIOS AND DISABLING SECURE BOOT. Took me a week to find this out, but I hope this helps out anyone with similar issues.

Answer (score 0):

Go to software & security settings and install driver for wifi adapter.
Sometimes WiFi driver are not installed.

Comment: hey, I managed to solve this by disabling secure boot. Thanks for the reply though!